# What causes IIS to show yellow page with red rectangle?

Tags: wcf, iis, permissions

I just tried to set up WCF web service with IIS, but IIS shows me a yellow page with a red rectangle in stead of the actual webpage. See the image below:

[image]

And there seems to be no logging anywhere of any errors. I have also tried to turn on the WCF system.diagnostics logging in the web.config file, but the resulting log file doesn't contain any errors.

Why am I seeing a yellow page with a red rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

This error turned out be caused by incorrectly configured permissions to the folder where the web service files were located. For IIS to have access to the web service files, I needed to grant access to the local **users** account.

Comment: Web content folder should have the required NTFS permissions (similar to `wwwroot` as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/default-permissions-user-rights#inetpubwwwroot)